# Nltk not running in c# window application form

Tags: c#, .net, module, nltk, ironpython

As i am running my index.py file in c# form (using ironpython), it is giving me error that couldn't find ntlk even though I already installed it. When i am running my index.py file in jupyter notebook seperately(to check) it is running perfectly.
So why am i having this problem in C# form?

Note- i am using visual studio 2022,and if you are going to suggest that install ironpython.stdlib too, i have installed it already.

Please help as i am having my presentation tomorrow .

I am using iron python, and have also installed ironpython.stdlib but i don't know how to use it(ironpython.stdlib). I saw someone saying that it will resolve that issue. So i hope someone can help me